# Use Enum to deserialised object from service response in Android Java

Tags: java, android, enums, deserialization

I got an enum method in an `Enums.java` class as below:

```
public enum Country
{
    @SerializedName("Germany")
    Germany,
    @SerializedName("Australia")
    Australia,
    @SerializedName("Canada")
    Canada;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

Then, I got an object which one of its attribute is `Enums.Country` as below:

```
@SerializedName("CountryName")
private Enums.Country countryName;

...
get
set
```

Basically, the country name comes back from a service call. However, at the moment the object only handles 3 countries which is Germany, Australia and Canada. If it is something else, it will be null. How can I avoid it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `toString()` is completely pointless.

Comment: How does your `Country` enum relate to `Enums.OverallVerificationStatusType`? From what you've shown us, these two pieces of code have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: sorry, check my edited code. It supposed to be Enums.Country

Comment: The correct solution  in this specific case is not to hard-wire country names into the application in the first place. Use a database table. One revolution tomorrow and there could be two new countries and one ex-country. It isn't something to hard-code. And, if you feel you must, put them all in. Now.

Comment: Well, there is other cases where you have fixed set of items such as ID, you will only allow driver license, passport or birth certificate. But some places also have nationality card, which is not in the above list.

Answer (score 1):

it's relatively easy, just define an **Unknown** value in your class like this:

```
public enum Country
{
    Unknown(Unknown"),
    @SerializedName("Germany")
    Germany,
    @SerializedName("Australia")
    Australia,
    @SerializedName("Canada")
    Canada;
}
```

Then write a custom deserializer for this `Enum` type and parse this `Enum` using it. For example the deserializer code using `GSON` would be like this:

```
JsonDeserializer<Country> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<Country>() {
    @Override
    public Country deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            return Country.valueOf(json.getAsString());
        } catch (Exception e){
            return Country.Unknown;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: So I need a field called Unknown in the Country class?